# View inside collectionView is not getting hide when I tapped on cell

Tags: swift, collectionview

I want to hide the bottom view attached with the collectionView cell according to the tap on the particular cell. I have tried doing this on "didSelectItemAt" function but it's not working.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.bottomView.isHidden = true    
    } 

   internal func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.lableArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        let item = lableArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.randomColor()
        cell.lable.text = item
        return cell
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Post more code or post screenshot of the UICollectionViewCell, does UICollectionViewCell comes from storyboard or code? Did you set the UICollectionViewDelegate property correctly?

Comment: I have designed it on storyboard. The green part including the bottom view is a cell. I have updated the code above.

Comment: Post the ViewController/ CollectionViewController code or storyboards

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by updating
let cell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

in didSelectItemAt with

let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

and adding the UICollectionViewDelegate with class.